# Can a Child Class be Added to a List<Parent> in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, list, types, collections

In my project, I have several classes inherited from a single parent class. I want to define a list that contains objects of each of these child classes.

```
public class Parent
{
    public string name;
}

public class Child1 : Parent
{
    public int property1;
}

public class Child2 : Parent
{
    public int property2;
}

public List<Parent> childrenOfParent = new List<Parent>(){
    new Child1(),
    new Child2()
};
```

Would this work or does a list have to be defined for the individual child classes?

Comment: Define *Would this work*. -- Do you just need the `name` property? Do you implement any Interface in your classes?

Comment: Why you just don't try it?

Comment: It'll work if you're not in a namespace! 

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this works, but you will only have access to the methods and properties of the parent class if you do this (unless you add an explicit cast), because the objects get casted to the type of the parent class when they are inserted into the `List`.

This is according to the standard C# casting rules, that a child class has an implicit cast to its parent class as explained [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).